# Sub-sub folders of WordPress Multisite subdirectory

Tags: multisite, directory, domain-mapping

I have the following situation.

I have created a WordPress Multisite for a client with "subdir" setup so all subsites are at;

`domain.com/site2`
`domain.com/site3`

Now client wants to have some subsites in "sub-sub-folders" so they exist as;

`domain.com/services/site2`
`domain.com/services/site3`

Is there any way to have it created like this? Done some research but I can really find any existing literature or help around this

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need a 'Multi Network', a many Multi-Sites Network. I build them here and there for different languages for one country, like

```
domain.example/
domain.example/1-country/
domain.example/1-country/language-1/
domain.example/1-country/language-2/
domain.example/1-country/language-3/
domain.example/2-country/
domain.example/2-country/language-1/
domain.example/2-country/language-2/
```

The core of WordPress doesn't support them and you need an enhancement. Ready to use is only possible with the help of a plugin, I know - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/ (https://github.com/stuttter/wp-multi-network)

Comment: Thanks @bueltge, I have installed the plugin and everything seems to be working in place right now. The main issues so far is that I cannot visit the WP Dashboard of a site created at `domain.example/2-country/language-1/`. It throws a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error and the frontend also throw 404 error for loading any WP asset.

Comment: Inside the readme of the plugin is the hint to a custom `sunrise.php`; you find it here https://paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multisite-with-nested-folder-paths